# Force Google spreadsheet to re-evaluate a cell (or all cells)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a spreadsheet that contains a lot of static configuration info. I'd like to not have to pass this large range around to every one of my custom functions; I do realize this breaks some of the assumptions and that I'll run into caching issues because of this, and not see all cells updating.

Is there any way for me to manually force a cell to completely re-evaluate itself (which I could call from an OnEdit trigger to the config area, or something similar)? It would be acceptable (though obviously not ideal) to force *all* cells to re-evaluate if that's the only way to do it.

I realize one way to counter this is to pass `GoogleClock()` around to every function, but I'm hoping to avoid that!

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: tag as google-apps-script? Also, I don't understand the question. I thought that a "write" triggers re-evaluation before a read. They added cache for writes to deal with the problem of re-evaluation after every write, because doing lots of writes used to be very very slow. (Note. I have not used in for a while).

Comment: Why do you need formulas to recalculate? I assume in my answer that you refer to custom formulas that are pulling data from external sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use googleclock, besides that no longer works on new sheets.
Pass the same cell reference to all your functions. With script, change that one cell to the current timestamp. All formulas will recalculate.

Comment: Pretty much the same thing. Not as clean, but I suppose it gets the job done. Thanks.

Comment: its not the same thing, googleclock will not work as a parameter in new sheets, and in old sheets it causes constant reevaluation every minute foreve with this you have control when to re-evaluate.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "chance that one cell to the current timestamp"?